# Equation $a^{n}+b^{n}=2008$ has no integers solutions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, contest-math

Prove that the equation $a^{n}+b^{n}=2008$ has no solutions for $a,b,n\in\mathbb{Z}, n\geq2.$

Comment: Someone working on Fermat's last theorem? :-)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Seems more like a math contest problem, @pushpen.paul - they often have years in them.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That reminds me, I have seen such *(not sure it is)* a problem in Olympiads.

Comment: Divide this into cases. Firstly odd and even $n$ then into subcases handling odd and even $a$ and $b$. Note that for odd $n$ $a+b|2008\implies a+b|8\implies 2|a+b$ and so on.

Comment: To simplify the computation, note that you can assume without loss of generality that $n$ is prime. Since $2008 = 2^3.251$, the relation $a^n + b^n\equiv 0 \pmod{2008}$ forces $a\equiv -b\pmod{251}$ for all $n$ not dividing $250$; that is, $n\not = 2, 5$. Some straightforward estimates with the fact that $|a - b| \geq 251$ (since $2008/2 = 1004$ is not a perfect $n$th power) eliminate the case $n \not = 2, 5$. For $n = 2$, consider the equation mod $4$ and use the fact that $2008\equiv 8 \pmod{16}$. The case $n = 5$ is harder, and I don't have any particularly clever idea for that.

Answer (score 5):

**Case 1** $n=2k$ is even. Then, $a^{2k},b^{2k} \equiv 0,1,4 \pmod{8}$ and therefore both $a,b$ need to be even.

Then $a^{2k}, b^{2k}$ are both divisible by $2^{2k}$. Thus $2^{2k}|2008$ which implies that $k=1$.

Writing $a=2a', b=2b'$ we have

$$a'^2+b'^2=502 \,.$$

Taking this equation modulo 8, there are no solutions.

**Case 2** $n=2k+1$ is odd. Then

$$(a+b)(a^{2k}-a^{2k-1}b+...+b^{2k})=2008 \,.$$

If $a,b$ have opposite parity, then both $a+b$ and $a^{2k}-a^{2k-1}b+...+b^{2k}$ are odd, which is not possible.

Therefore, $a,b$ are both odd or both even.

**Subcase 2a** $a,b$ are both even. Then $2^{2k+1}|a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1}=2008$ which implies that $2k+1=3$.

Writing $a=2a', b=2b'$ we have

$$a'^3+b'^3=251 \,.$$

Then 
$$(a'+b')(a'^2-a'b'+b'^2)=251 \,.$$

Using the fact that $251$ is prime, there are only two possible factorizations, and in each case there is no solution.

**Subcase 2b** $a,b$ are both odd. Then $a+b$ is even and $(a^{2k}-a^{2k-1}b+...+b^{2k})$ is odd. As 251 is prime, there are only two possibilities

$$a+b=8$$
$$a^{2k}-a^{2k-1}b+...+b^{2k}=251$$
or
$$a+b=2008$$
$$a^{2k}-a^{2k-1}b+...+b^{2k}=1$$

At least one of $a$ and $b$ has to be positive.

- If both $a,b$ are positive, it is easy to show that $a+b=2008, a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1}=2008$ is impossible.

The equation $a+b=8, a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1}=2008$ leads to only two possibilities: 
$$7^{2k+1}+1=2008$$
or
$$3^{2k+1}+5^{2k+1}=2008$$
which can easily be eliminated.

- If only one of $a,b$ is positive, by symmetry, we can assume that $a >0, b<0$. Let $c=-b >0$.

Then the two equations reduce to
$$(8+c)^{2k+1}-c^{2k+1}=2008$$
or
$$(2008+c)^{2k+1}-c^{2k+1}=2008$$
The second one can easely be eliminated by observing that 
$$(2008+c)^{2k+1} > 2008^{2k+1}+c^{2k+1}$$

For the first,
$$2008=(8+c)^{2k+1}-c^{2k+1} >8^{2k+1}+c^{2k+1}-c^{2k+1}=8^{2k+1}$$

This implies that $k=1$ and it is easy to show that
$$(8+c)^3-c^3=2008$$
has no solution with $c>0$.

Comment: Why $a\equiv b(\mod{8})$ in subcase 2b?

Comment: @MariusDamian Was a mistake, I think I fixed now that c ase.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution!

Answer (score 3):

The bad and brute-force approach would be like this:

You see that $2^{11} > 2008$, so you only have to consider $ 2 \leq n \leq 10$
It will become tedious, but you will probably finish it in about 30-50 min.

You can neglect $n = 6$  pretty soon from FLT, since $2008 \equiv 6 \bmod 7$ and $a^6 + b^6 \equiv (0,1) + (0,1) \not\equiv 6 \bmod 7$

Same goes for $n = 4$ and $n = 10$, checking with $\bmod 5$ and $\bmod 11$ respectively.

Comment: Nice. But I guess there is a nicer solution too!

Comment: What if $b$ is negative?

Comment: It will still be congruent to $1 \bmod 7$ if b is not a multiple of 7.

Comment: The point is that you can have $n \geq 11$ odd...So considering $ 2 \leq n \leq 10$ is not enough.

Comment: n ≤ 10 is fine: a, b = 0 or ±1 doesn't give a solution. Above that the difference between two powers is at least 2^11 - 1 = 2047.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer but a simplification perhaps:

Well $$a^n+b^n\equiv 2008\equiv 0 \text{ mod 2}$$ $$\implies a^n\equiv -b^n\equiv b^n \text{ mod 2}$$
$$\implies a\equiv b \text{ mod 2}$$

Thus either both $a$ and $b$ are both odd or they are both even.

Now suppose both $a$ and $b$ are even then we can write:

$$a=2c \text{ and } b=2d \text{ so that we get:}$$

$$(2c)^n+(2d)^n=2008$$

$$\implies 2^n(c^n+d^n)=2008$$
$$\implies 2^n\mid 2008$$

But sense: $2008=2^3\times 251$ we know that $n$ can not exceed $3$.

---

Thus we can deduce from this that either both $a$ and $b$ are even or they are both odd. If they are both even then it suffices to show that there are no integer solutions $c$ and $d$ to:

$$c^2+d^2=502 \text{ and } c^3+d^3=251$$